# Getting different result even after having the same subset of data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have tried searching for possible similar questions, but I have not been able to find any so far. My problem is:

I want to use cross-validation using non-overlapping subsets of data using `KFold`. What I did was to create subsets using `KFold` and fix the outcome by setting `randome_state` to a certain integer. When I print out the subsets multiple times results look OK. However, the problem is when I use the same subsets on a model multiple times using `model.predict` (meaning running my code multiple times), I get different results. Naturally, I suspect there is something wrong with my implementation of training model. But I cannot figure out what it is. I would very much appreciate a hint. Here is my code:

```
random.seed(42)
# define K-fold cross validation test harness
kf = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(data):l
    print ('Train', train_index, '\nTest ', test_index)
    # create model
    testX= data[test_index]
    trainX = data[train_index]

    testYcheck = labels[test_index]
    testP = Path[test_index]
    # convert the labels from integers to vectors
    trainY = to_categorical(labels[train_index], num_classes=2)
    testY = to_categorical(labels[test_index], num_classes=2)

    # construct the image generator for data augmentation
    aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

    # train the network
    print("[INFO] training network...")
    model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
        validation_data=(testX, testY), 
        steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)

    #predict the test data
    y_pred = model.predict(testX)

    predYl = []

    for element in range(len(y_pred)):
        if y_pred[element,1] > y_pred[element,0]:
            predYl.append(1)
        else:
            predYl.append(0)


    pred_Y= np.array(predYl)

    # Compute confusion matrix
    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(testYcheck, pred_Y)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

    print (cnf_matrix)
```

Comment: Can you set numpy random seed as well? `np.random.seed(42)`

Comment: @SelçukGülcan actually, I have already set the random.seed(42). I have not wrote the entire code as I thought it might not be relevant. I will add this to the question.

Comment: random.seed and np.random.seed are two different things. Please use np.random.seed().

Comment: @VivekKumar my apologies, yes I used np.random.seed and it works.